# How to connect to MySQL Server on local desktop computer on Windows 10 using named-pipe connection?

Tags: mysql, database

How to connect to MySQL Server on local desktop computer on Windows 10 using named-pipe connection? What do I need to edit in my.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

Clients determine what type of connection to make as follows:

If the host is not specified or is localhost, a connection to the local host is assumed:

On Windows, the client connects using a shared-memory connection, if the server has shared-memory connections enabled.

On Unix, the client connects using a Unix socket file. The `--socket` option or the `MYSQL_UNIX_PORT` environment variable may be used to specify the socket name.

On Windows, if host is ., or TCP/IP is not enabled and `--socket` is not specified or the host is empty, the client connects using a named pipe, if the server has named-pipe connections enabled. If named-pipe connections are not enabled or if the user making the connection is not a member of the Windows group specified by the `named_pipe_full_access_group` server system variable, an error occurs.

Otherwise, TCP/IP is used.

The `--protocol` option enables you to establish a particular type of connection even when the other options would normally default to some other protocol. That is, `--protocol` may be given to specify the connection protocol explicitly and override the preceding rules, even for localhost.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html